# Send array to function in BACI (C--)

Tags: c-minus-minus

I want to send an array to a function then print all of the elements. I have an error.

.LST file is:

> BACI System: C-- to PCODE Compiler, 16:59  27 Oct 2005
>   Source file: 1.cm  Fri Nov 01 03:16:20 2019
>    line  pc
>      1    0
>      2    0
>      3    0
>      4    0  void Print(int a[])
>   Error near '[', line 4 of file 1.cm:
>   **   syntax error 
>   Because of 1 error the PCODE file will not execute

Baci reference is:
http://inside.mines.edu/~tcamp/baci/baci_index.html

> C:\badosxe> bacc 1.cm Error near '[', line 4 of file 1.cm: **   syntax error>>Because of 1 error the PCODE file will not execute Pcode and tables are stored in 1.pco Compilation listing is stored in 1.lst

```
void Print(int a[])
{
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i = i + 1)
        {
        cout<<a[i];
        }
}

main()
{
    cout << endl;
 cobegin
    {
    int a[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};

    Print(a);

    }
}
```

Comment: Don't post images unless necessary. Post the error as text. And please read [ask]

Comment: Please provide a URL to C--, and then please [edit] your question and post the error message as text. Yes, you can copy text from the command prompt! Just one observation: If C-- works similarly to C/C++ the indices count beginning with 0, not 1. The last element of a 5-element array is then indexed by 4.